# How can I write via http Request from my UI to a table?

Tags: java, database, http

I want to write via http request from my UI to a table.

I know that I will have to use @POST but how can I implement that the table shown in my UI will write to a table in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your servlet need to write this for retrieve the parameter:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String nome = req.getParameter("nome");
        ...
}
```

in your jsp page u need to use a form, like this:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    <br /><input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```